# get value of form field using the input type id - in views.py django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model : as below

```
class Pockets(models.Model):
    pocket_owner = models.CharField(default="None",max_length=50)
    pocket_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50)
    pocket_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    pocket_1000 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_500 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_100 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_50 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_20 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_10 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_5 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pocket_change = models.FloatField(default=0)

    initial_amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    sum_pocket = models.FloatField(default=0)

    pocket_total = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # self.old money wont add here , as it will duplicate records .
        self.sum_pocket = ( self.pocket_1000 * 1000 ) + (self.pocket_500 * 500) + (self.pocket_100 * 100) + \
                         (self.pocket_50 * 50) + (self.pocket_20 * 20 ) + (self.pocket_10 * 10) + \
                         (self.pocket_5 * 5) + (self.pocket_2 * 2 ) + self.pocket_1 + self.pocket_change

        super(Pockets, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pocket_name
```

and corresponding form like as below :

```
class PocketsTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PocketsTransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pocket_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text','class':'pocketTotalAmount'}),max_length=300,required=False)
    pocket_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text','class':'pocketTotalAmount'}),max_length=500,label="Description",required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Pockets
        exclude = ['pocket_owner']
        fields = ('pocket_name','pocket_description','pocket_1000','pocket_500','pocket_100','pocket_50','pocket_20','pocket_10','pocket_5','pocket_2','pocket_1','pocket_change')
```

now in views.py i am rendering it using 2 forms and auto_id so i can differenciate between 2 fields using ids

```
form1 = PocketsTransactionForm(instance=p1,auto_id='pocketTransaction_p1_%s')
form2 = PocketsTransactionForm(instance=p2,auto_id='pocketTransaction_p2_%s')
return render_to_response('money/addPocketTransactionsShow.html', {'form1':form1,'form2':form2,}, context)
```

**Problem**

How to get the value of pocket_name from both fields via request.POST .. see code below :

```
@login_required
def addPocketTransactionsShow(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print " pocket_name from form 1 is : ",request.POST.get("pocketTransaction_p1_pocket_name")  
# how to get value in above line ... ids for pocket name 1 and 2 are pocketTransaction_p1_pocket_name and pocketTransaction_p2_pocket_name
```

Any Advices ?

Comment: The view where you render the forms and the view addPocket are deferents views?

Comment: Yes these views are different

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required
def addPocketTransactionsShow(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = PocketsTransactionForm(instance=p1,auto_id='pocketTransaction_p1_%s')
        form2 = PocketsTransactionForm(instance=p2,auto_id='pocketTransaction_p2_%s')
            if form1.is_valid():
                pocket_name_1 = form1.cleaned_data['pocket_name']
            if form2.is_valid():
                pocket_name_2 = form2.cleaned_data['pocket_name'] 
        # do what you want with pocket_name_1 and pocket_name_2
```

Comment: i cant do this because i dont have instance p1 and p2 here , p1 and p2 are actually the names of those pockets , but i am passing them from some other view .